# Windows environment license discovery

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, licensing

Is there some tool from Microsoft or from somebody else that can scan the network and discover the licenses keys from windows machines (Windows 7, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2, Server 2003, Office, SQL Server)?
We've used Spiceworks but it doesn't scan good, i.e. it cannot retrieve license keys.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. VAMT -

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11936

Volume Activation Management Tool

It can scan and read and replace the keys, as well as do activatoin operations for a number of computers (in case you need to replace and reactivate the keys).

Does not handle Office, though, or SQL Server.

THAT SAID: You should consider moving to a centrally managed solution using a key management server. None of the machines I am responsible for HAS a windows or office key assigned, they all use centrally disposed temporary license from a KMS install.

Comment: could you please give me a link for the solution that you use so that I can read more about it? Tnx

Comment: Type "Key Management Server" into "http://www.google.com".